# How to decode password save with md5() in mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, md5

I have very simple query .

I am fetching user name and password from a Mysql DB using php.

The password is in md5() encoded. Can any one help me out

script

```
while($rfg=mysql_fetch_array($rc)){
            //print_r($rfg);
              echo $_POST['im_password'] = $rfg['Password'];
              echo $_POST['im_user'] = $rfg['Nombre'];

        }
```

how I can decode the md5 password to real text in php ??

Thanks in Advance

Comment: `md5` is a hash so you can not decode it.

Comment: how to recreate the living cow from the beefburger? You can't. Now explain why you need to

Comment: @MarkBaker: That hits it perfectly haha :D.

Comment: Didn't Marc B come up with something like that last week? The hashed Angus, let's try and put him back together after passing him in the meat grinder. He comes up with some good ones ;) unless he got that one from you Mark.

Comment: You can't decode the password encoded with md5.

Comment: apart from the "you can't", let me add that you shouldn't use `md5` to hash (not encrypt) passwords, and you should use a salt.

Comment: @Fred-ii- it's been doing the rounds for a while now

Comment: @MarkBaker Always nice to see people with a sense of humour ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of using md5 is that you CANT decrypt it that easely. You could for example use it to compare md5(user_input) with the hash in the database (login system).

If you really need to get a plain-text (which I dont support) you could try using dictionary-attacks. Everything beside that (bruteforcing) wouldnt be worth it according to the needed calculation power.

Answer (score -1):

MD5 can't be decoded unless you are using rainbow tables.
The way to check if a user entered a correct password is to hash his entered password with md5 and check it with the password in the database.

Comment: Not exactly correct. The best way would be using bruteforcing which would be a question of time. There is no guarantee to decrypt it with a rainbow-table. Not to mention it wouldnt even be real "decrypting".

Comment: You're not necessarily guaranteed to have found the original password, even if you do brute force or rainbow table correctly, you can only say that you've found a match, it may be a clash

Comment: @MarkBaker: Hah yeah. Taking the possibilities really strong you are right. I have to say I never got that case. At least not for something beside strings like "1234".